# what is the Mariabackup date time of the backup data?

Tags: mariadb

When we complete a Mariabackup, what is the date time of backup data ?
When the Mariabackup is running transactions can be added by users, so the backup datetime will contains data just until the backup begins or until is complete.

Thanks in Advance,
Adelino.

what is the Mariabackup  date time of the backup data ?

Answer (score 2):

In the backup directory there is a `xtrabackup_info` file that contains the start and end time of the backup.

e.g:

```
$ more xtrabackup_backupfiles/xtrabackup_info 
uuid = c2c8de3f-dd77-11ed-bed6-f47b09a650a9
name = 
tool_name = mariabackup
tool_command = --no-defaults -S /tmp/build-mariadb-server-10.6.sock --user dan --backup
tool_version = 10.6.13-MariaDB
ibbackup_version = 10.6.13-MariaDB
server_version = 10.6.13-MariaDB
start_time = 2023-04-18 09:29:53
end_time = 2023-04-18 09:29:55
lock_time = 0
binlog_pos = 
innodb_from_lsn = 0
innodb_to_lsn = 41380
partial = N
incremental = N
format = file
compressed = N
```

Because of the way the redo log is saved, the backup, when `--prepare`d reflects the time of the completion of the backup. Or more accurately, to the `innodb_to_lsn` value representing the last committed innodb transaction in the redo log.